# Untitled Error comes from coldfusion-ajax

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting an error but there is no caption on it. There is a cfloop looping over the result set which comes from a Stored Procedure. Each row makes an AJAX request to another page and fetch some information. In that AJAX called page, CF prints an error. For example, there are 100 rows come from Stored Procedure. While looping through that data set, 2nd and 50th rows throw error but other 98 rows doesn`t. Next time 4th, 7th and 15th rows throw error, other 97 doesn`t. The message is shown in below.
I have checked my code there is no problem. Moreover there is no stability.

```
<title>Error Occurred While Processing Request</title>
<font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 16pt/18pt verdana">
    The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.<br>
    Please contact the website administrator.
</font>
<br><br>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#000808" bgcolor="#e7e7e7">
<tbody><tr>
    <td bgcolor="#000066">
        <font style="COLOR: white; FONT: 11pt/13pt verdana" color="white">
        The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes. 
        </font>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
</tr><tr>
    <td bgcolor="#4646EE">
        <font style="COLOR: white; FONT: 11pt/13pt verdana" color="white">
        Error Occurred While Processing Request
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">
        <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td id="tableProps2" align="left" valign="middle" width="500">
                <h1 id="textSection1" style="COLOR: black; FONT: 13pt/15pt verdana">

                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tablePropsWidth" width="400" colspan="2">
                <font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">

                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">
                Resources:
                <ul>

        <li>Check the <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/prod_doc" target="new">ColdFusion documentation</a> to verify that you are using the correct syntax.</li>
        <li>Search the <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/prod_support/" target="new">Knowledge Base</a> to find a solution to your problem.</li>

                </ul>
                <p>
            </p></font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">Browser&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">Remote Address&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">my_ip</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">Referrer&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">http://my_host_ip/path/file.cfm?CFID=1234&amp;CFTOKEN=es785e1ff5b98f53-E3FC4F25-0917-2A90-2CA672635042EEDE</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">Date/Time&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                    <td><font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">31-Jan-17 08:13 AM</font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>


            <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <font style="FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana;">
                    Stack Trace 
                </font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="cf_stacktrace">
                    <font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <pre>java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(WeakHashMap.java:762)
        at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:801)
        at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:799)
        at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:523)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTracker.__AW_getAllPrimitiveMap(MemoryTracker.java:92)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTracker.getAllPrimitiveMap(MemoryTracker.java)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTracker.getEstimatedMemory(MemoryTracker.java:117)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.SessionMemoryMonitor$TopMemoryUsedSessions.compareThreshold(SessionMemoryMonitor.java:166)
        at coldfusion.monitor.util.MonitorList.add(MonitorList.java:102)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.SessionMemoryMonitor.record(SessionMemoryMonitor.java:49)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.SessionMemoryMonitor.record(SessionMemoryMonitor.java:37)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryMonitor.record(MemoryMonitor.java:261)
        at coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryRequestEventHandler.onRequestComplete(MemoryRequestEventHandler.java:23)
        at coldfusion.monitor.event.RequestMonitorEventProcessor.onRequestComplete(RequestMonitorEventProcessor.java:247)
        at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:46)
        at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.__AW_invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
        at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java)
        at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
        at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
        at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
        at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
        at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
        at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
        at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
        at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
        at coldfusion.CfmServlet.__AW_service(CfmServlet.java:200)
        at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.__AW_service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
        at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.__AW_service(FilterChain.java:101)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.__AW_invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
        at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
    </pre></font></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>

    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Error messages inside html tags don't really constitute useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed CF 9.0.2 and problem solved.